# Unity's animation system is flipping out. Rotates only the long way around

Tags: animation, unity, rotation

I really dont know what is going on or how to even explain the problem so I made a gif. Its not a really well made gif so please bare with it.[image]

Comment: I thought Unity was animating with quaternions, not euler angles. Could it be that you somehow forced it to animate with euler angles?

Comment: It forces itself to animate with euler angles . Every damn time. I have to go and manually change it. No idea what went wrong.

Comment: It is very hard to tell what your actually trying to do from the GIF. What degrees are you trying to rotate between? What axis? Positive or negative?

Answer (score 1):

Expand the dropdown. Manually change the z-axis rotation in negative equivalent. Like `350 degrees` to `-10 degrees`.

[image]

While testing, Unity 5.2.5 doesn't convert negative values but 5.3.5+ seems to be converting them to positive equivalent.

Comment: this only fixes it for the specific animation. I need a way to fix this all together. I can be going and manually changing keyframe values for each rotation on each new animation. I swear unity did not do this yesterday.